# Mysqli update int fail

Tags: php, mysqli, int

It's pretty simple, and also confusing.

```
if(!$query = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE personnage SET ps = 2 WHERE 1;"))
    print("Erreur à lors du heal 2.");
```

This SIMPLE update work fine WHEN ps is positive AND ONLY positive
When I reach 0, this SIMPLE update doesn't work and let the value to 0. (By doesn't work I mean, there's no error, just the sql doesn't change the value)
The column is an INT.
Is that a mysqli issue ? When I execute this SQL in my DB it work perfectly, whatever the value.
Can someone solve this mystery.

Comment: remove `;` from query. And start using `{` `}` for code blocks

Comment: both of your advices aren't related to my problem, even if I'm curious about how this is supposed to be better

Answer (score 0):

Try  -

```
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE personnage SET ps = 2 WHERE ps = 0")
```

Comment: Already tried, like I wrote, this is working even with the ; but only when ps is different of 0

Comment: if you want to update it if it is 0 then add the condition..Updated the answer.

Comment: I just tried this, and... no, still 0... It's not about selecting the good personnage, when I have 5 personnages with differents ps values, and 2 with 0, and I make this update on every personnages, only theses two doesn't change, i finish with 2,2,2,0,0.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've found the problem, it's not related to any syntax or whatever, I had in like 1000 lignes after this something putting the value to 0 again, I just didn't looked far enough.

Thanks anyways